# Uploading file to amazon S3 via curl has extra directories

Tags: php, curl, amazon-s3, zip

I am using curl to upload some zipped files to amazon.  Everything is working perfectly fine but then when I go to test and download the newly uploaded .zip and unzip it then it has the path from where the .zip was created on my local computer:

```
/Users/my-computer/Desktop/myZips/nameofmyzip.zip
```

I don't want people to unzip their download and see all these extra directories.  I have tried using `basename()` for my `$filePath` but then my script didn't work because it couldn't find the path to my file anymore.

My file in my curl command is using CurlFile:

```
$filePath = '/Users/my-computer/Desktop/myZips/'.$file.'';
$fileName = ''.$file.'';

$ch = curl_init('https://' . $bucket . '.s3-' . $region . '.amazonaws.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'Content-Type' =>  $fileType,
    'acl' => $acl,
    'key' => $fileName,
    'policy' =>  $policy,
    'x-amz-algorithm' => 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
    'x-amz-credential' => $credential,
    'x-amz-date' => $longDate,
    'x-amz-signature' => $signature,
    'file' => new CurlFile($filePath, $fileType, $fileName)
    ]);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I know that I need the path in order for the curl command to work correctly but I don't want the file to be uploaded on amazon S3 with all those extra directories.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Were the files that you zipped in /Users/my-computer/Desktop/myZips/ ? zipping software included the full path by default.

Comment: I am confused by the question.  I am zipping up a file and then taking that zipped file and uploading it on amazon.  when I go to download it instead of just getting the file when i unzip I get the entire path to my file /Users/my-computer/Desktop/myZips/nameOfMyUnzippeFile

Comment: Open the original zip file and see if the path is there

Comment: Ya when i open the original it has that path inside of it as well.